# Array as response in service

Tags: ros, rosservice, msg, array, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to create a service that returns an array of a custom msg. However, when I call this using **roservice call /myservice [input params...]**  I get the following error:

```
ERROR: service [/myservice] responded with an error: service cannot process request: handler returned wrong number of values: Invalid number of arguments, args should be ['parsed'] args are(operation: travel_to
target: a1
time_step: 0, operation:open ... )
```

Based on this I assumed that the type I  was returning was wrong, so outputted the type just before the return statement in Python, however they seem to be what I expect them to be based on the  documentation [here](http://wiki.ros.org/msg)

```
type: type 'list'
element type: class 'asp_model.msg._SubGoal.SubGoal'
```

.srv file

```
string goal
string entityA
string entityB
---
Subgoal[] parsed
```

.msg file

```
string operation
string target
int16 time_step
```

Some additional info:
I also tried simply returning a list of integers **[1, 2, 3]**, which with the response type set to **Int16[]** which resulted in the same error. I'm running on ROS Hydro, Ubuntu 12.04, no other errors show up when running catkin_make or running the server

Any ideas on how to go about fixing this? I'm not sure if I'm completely misunderstanding the error message!

**Edit1**:
Python on server, I've removed code indicated by the '...' as its some lengthy regex and string parsing stuff:

```
    def parse_answer(self, raw):
        parsed = []  # Use this to save list of SubGoals
        ....
        ....
        for step in anslist:
            ....
            ....
            if step:
                parsed.append(SubGoal(operation=operation[0], target=target[0], time_step=int(time_step)))

        return parsed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202710/array-as-response-in-service/) by [genericsoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/20987/genericsoup/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2015-02-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-02-09**:
Please post the python code for your server. I suspect you're returning the wrong type.

**Comment by [genericsoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/20987/genericsoup/) on 2015-02-09**:
Edited question to include relevant code - unsure if you get a notification when I edit, hence the comment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@ahendrix is right. You returned the wrong type.

Have a detailed look at the [python service tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingServiceClient.Writing_a_Service_Node).

You have to return an instance of `<YourServiceType>Response` instead of a list of `SubGoal`. In this Response you can store the SubGoals.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2